# Mixing Wildcards and Parameters in Express

Tags: express, url-routing

I have web content generated by [Minecraft Overviewer](https://overviewer.org/) in:

`/home/mc/backups/servername/latest/overviewer`

I have a *very* simple server with express/nodejs. Here is my app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
// Each server's root points to the latest overviewer page                    |
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
app.get('/minecraft/:server/*', function(req, res) {
    console.log('HELLO?');
    res.send('Finally some luck!');

    /*
    var
        server = req.params.server,
        file = req.params[0] ? req.params[0] : 'index.html',
        dir = '../backups/' + server + '/latest/overviewer';

    res.sendFile(file, { root: dir });
    */
});

app.use(express.static('www'));

app.listen(80, function () {
    console.log('Web server listening on port 80');
});
```

I included a little more code than what is running so you can see my intent in case this is an xy kind of problem. I'm wanting to route static files, but I don't think I can use `express.static` because I want the URL to be mapped a little differently than my file structure (and based on a server name).

So what's the problem with my simple server? When I try and navigate to `mysite.com/minecraft/isopre` I see a white page saying `Cannot GET /minecraft/isopre`. If I remove the `*` from the end of the string I'm routing on line 7 I see `Finally some luck!`. But I want the star there so I can map `mysite.com/minecraft/isopre` to `index.html` or `mysite.com/minecraft/isopre/overviewer.js`.

So what's the right way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to perform desirable operation i suggest you to use **?** symbol for regular expression:

```
app.get('/minecraft/:server/:file?', function(req, res, next) {
    if('undefined' != typeof req.params.file && req.params.file) {
        var file = req.params.file;
    }

    if('undefined' != typeof req.params.server && req.params.server) {
        var server = req.params.server;
    }

});
```

In this case :file become optional and node.js won't fail your entire application if wildcard is absent.

Hereby, if req.params.file variable is undefined you could serve index.html file.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks :) I figured it was simple